# Cannot debug in chrome dev tool when setting on "optimization": true in angular.json

Tags: angular, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When i set optimizations = true in angular.json, we encounter issues while debugging in chrome devtools and Breakpoints aren't hit , or on the wrong line(s) in the corresponding typescript files.

```
  "local": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "hidden": false,
                "vendor": false
              },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is an Angular 12 project? There's similar questions, but with slightly different wording, so they aren't easy to find...like [Angular 12 Debug source code not available in Chrome Developer tools was fine in Angular 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706253/angular-12-debug-source-code-not-available-in-chrome-developer-tools-was-fine-in)

Essentially you need, as you likely discovered, your angular.json config options to be updated. In a location such as `architect -> someNamedBuilder -> configurations -> development` or just at the level of `architect -> someNamedBuilder` under `options`:

```
        {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
```

Without this configuration, it seems that you are not able to stop at breakpoints within chrome dev tools.

Some of the documentation is here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config but it doesn't help much with this issue...