# extension error on Angular-Chrome DevTools "Angular DevTools only supports development builds

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, angular13

ِAfter updating my Project from angular 11 to 13, I get this problem:
I added this block on Angular.json but It didn't work

"development": {
"buildOptimizer": false,
"optimization": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"namedChunks": true
}

any suggestion to fix this issue please

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g9c6.png)

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916159/3025289

Answer (score 0):

In your angular.json navigate to

> architect -> build -> configurations

and add these lines, below the definition of the production build:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    // already there!
  },
  "development": { // this is new!
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true
  }
},
"defaultConfiguration": "production"
```