# Unable to Debug Angular 12 project in Chrome Dev tools after upgrade

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, package.json, angular.json

This project has been upgraded from Angular 6 to Angular 12, one version at a time. The project compiles and works, but I cannot debug it in Chrome dev tools anymore. I do not see my source code. I tried to 'Add folder to Workspace' in Chrome, but then my file gets locked. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. The Chrome version I have is Version 108.0.5359.95 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have tried to change my angular.json after reading another post [Angular 12 Debug source code not available in Chrome Developer tools was fine in Angular 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706253/angular-12-debug-source-code-not-available-in-chrome-developer-tools-was-fine-in)

but it is not working for me.
Here's my angular.json

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "xlsx",
              "rxjs/BehaviorSubject",
              "rxjs/add/observable/throw",
              "rxjs/add/operator/catch",
              "rxjs/Observable",
              "rxjs/operators/map",
              "rxjs/operators/tap"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "development": {
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-name:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app-name:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app-name:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-name:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app-name-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app-name:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app-name",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hierarchy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prodbuild": "ng build --configuration production --aot=true --output-hashing none",
    "build": "ng build --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.15",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^7.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^4.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^6.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.5",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "angular2-notifications": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "dns-packet": "^5.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0"
  }
}
```

Also, I'm building using command ng build --watch and it is still working. Is this command still appropriate or would you suggest something else?

Comment: What happens if you throw `debugger` in some function call or component and reload page with dev tools open?

Comment: I put debugger couple of places. It breaks in main.js. Only style.js and main.js are open by default. If I press Ctrl+P in dev tools to open a file, all it shows in .scss, .png files. If I search for a .ts filename, it says 'No files found'. So debugger does work, but my concern is if that is the only way to debug now?

Comment: If you're using VSCode or an intelliJ IDE then you can set it up to actually use breakpoints inside of your IDE. It's been a few years since I used angular 6 but I've not seen ts source files in the debugger in any version since A10

Comment: We use Visual Studio IDE since Angular project has business logic and data access layer in C#. The only way I have been using to debug Angular code is Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Visual studio has a nice write up on how to use their debugger (the power of Google) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial